# jquery.form and cross-domain requests for file upload

Tags: jquery, iframe, file-upload, jquery-forms-plugin, asyncfileupload

I'm trying to make a cross domain file upload form work using jquery form plugin, but I keep getting the following error in firebug console:

```
Permission denied to access property 'document'
```

It happens on the following line of jquery.form plugin

```
403: var doc = frame.contentWindow ? frame.contentWindow.document : frame.contentDocument ? frame.contentDocument : frame.document;
```

And If I use safari, I get this error:

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://s1.test-host/index.php/upload/start?is-async=1 from frame with URL http://test-host/index.php/main/. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

The html for the for looks like this:

```
  <form action="http://s1.test-host//index.php/upload/start" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" id="upload-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1204000"  />
      <label for="file-input">Input File</label>
      <input type="file" name="file" value="" id="file-input" alt="Input File"  />
      <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Convert" id="start-upload" />
  </form>
```

The javascript looks like this:

```
$(this).ajaxForm ({
    beforeSubmit: onFileFormSubmit,     // pre-submit callback
    success:      onFileFormSubmitEnd,  // post-submit callback
    resetForm:    true,             // reset the form after successful submit
    dataType:     'json',           // force response type to JSON
    iframe:       true              // force the form to be submitted using an iframe
});
```

The target php page has this:

```
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']) {
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
        header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
    }
   ... // Usual upload handling code
```

But nothing seems to be working. I've even tried to change 'dataType' to 'jsonp' and also changed to form mothod from 'post' to 'get' but all that is to no avail, I still keep getting the same error. If I look at the server the file does actually get uploaded but javascript is not able to call the success function.

After googling I've found that there could be other solutions like 'JQuery File Upload' or 'plupload' but I really need something simple I don't want to use HTML5 features.

Comment: can you upload to same domain and use server to send to other domain? Problem is AJAX doesn't do file upload so uses hidden Iframe, then response is another domain so no iframe access

Answer (score 1):

The file upload plugin is using an iframe to upload the file. Since you can't post cross-domain without proper CORS headers and you cant supply CORS headers to an iframe, this simply isn't possible. The best option option is to instead post it to your server, then move it to the cross-domain as needed using server-side code.

Answer (score 0):

I know you don't want anything fancy but for cross-domain in browsers without full XHR support, I recommend using the **jQuery-File-Upload** plugin. It uses an iframe to upload a file to another domain. It needs more work though:

- You need to change your upload server response to what the plugin [expects](http://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Setup)
- You need to upload the [result.html](http://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Cross-domain-uploads) somewhere in your original server to get the response

If you don't want the UI stuff, you can use the *basic* version of the plugin.